# DB2 JDBC connection url with instance name

Tags: java, database, jdbc, db2

Current JDBC URL using looks like
jdbc:db2://server:446/DBname

Want to connect to a different instance by providing the instance name. 
How should be the connection string for this?

Answer (score 1):

In jdbc you do not connect to an instance, instead you connect to a database. It is possible to ATTACH to a DB2-instance but normally you don't want to do that unless you are a DBA.  To specify a different DB2-instance, mention its hostname(or IP-address, or Virtual-IP-address) *and* its port-number. If a hostname runs multiple DB2-instances, each DB2-instance will have a unique port-number on that hostname.

Comment: Thanks, for the responce. 
we have DB2 multiple instances on the same host with same port number and the DB person requesting us to connect to one of the instance. 
From what you have mentioned looks like the port numbers have to be different on the same host. 
Not sure what needs to be done.

Comment: Each DB2-instance needs a unique port-number if they run on the same hostname. Inside each DB2-instance there can be multiple local databases.

Comment: It is the job of the DBA to configure DB2 to accept your connections by listening on a suitable port, and to tell you the hostname/portnumber/database-name.  Ask your DBA for help.

Comment: I'll. Thanks, for all your help.